# HTML value store list of dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to loop through an array of objects stored in the `value-media` attribute of my `button`.

I'm able to get data from `value-media` and show it, but I can't loop through this data - it treats it like one long string (I'm guessing) and showing "undefined"

```js
var medias = [button.getAttribute('value-media')]
console.log(medias)

$.each(medias, function(index, value) {
  alert(value.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="editUserBtn" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editUser" value-userid="34" value-username="CUSTOMER1_TEST2" value-media="[{'id': '50', 'name': 'CUSTOMER1_Windows Notification', 'sendto': ['test@test.com', 'test2@test.com']}, {'id': '51', 'name': 'CUSTOMER1_ALL', 'sendto': ['test@test.com', 'test2@test.com']}]">
  <img src="/static/images/settings_black_24dp.svg" title="Edit user"/>
</button>
```

Could you help me to make it working? I need to go throught this data and for each dictionary in list take ID :(

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(button.getAttribute('value-media'))` to convert it to an array of objects.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't define your own attributes like this. HTML has standard `data-XXX` attributes for application-defined data.

Comment: And then if you use jQuery's `.data()` method, it will automatically parse it as JSON if it's valid syntax.

Comment: @Barmar JSON.parse() won't work here unfortunately as it's not valid JSON. jQuery's `data()` method won't auto-deserialize it for the same reason

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that. Can the data be fixed to be valid JSON? It looks like Python syntax, so the application that creates it could use `json.dumps()` instead of `str()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
It's working now.
Here is the solution:

```js
var medias = $(button).data('media')
var mediasJSON = JSON.parse(medias.replace(/\'/g, "\""))
    $.each(mediasJSON, function(index, value) {
        alert(value.name + value.id)
      });
```